# Small icon doesn't show properly in android sometimes

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]

I have situation that sometimes my notification small icon doesn't show properly so it's only appear brown square icon.
my code :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                NotificationChannel mChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel(id);


                if (mChannel == null) {
                    mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, rm.getNotification().getTitle(), importance);
                    mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                    mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                    notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                }

                nBuilder.setContentTitle(rm.getNotification().getTitle().isEmpty() ? "" : rm.getNotification().getTitle())                            // required
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_push_notification)   // required
                        .setContentText(rm.getNotification().getBody().isEmpty() ? "" : rm.getNotification().getBody()) // required
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentIntent(pending)
                        .setTicker(rm.getNotification().getBody().isEmpty() ? "" : rm.getNotification().getBody())
                        .setColor(0x008000)
                        .setContentIntent(pending)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(rm.getNotification().getBody() == null ? "" : rm.getNotification().getBody()))
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            } else {

                nBuilder.setContentTitle(rm.getNotification().getTitle().isEmpty() ? "" : rm.getNotification().getTitle())                            // required
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_push_notification)   // required
                        .setContentText(rm.getNotification().getBody().isEmpty() ? "" : rm.getNotification().getBody()) // required
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentIntent(pending)
                        .setTicker(rm.getNotification().getBody().isEmpty() ? "" : rm.getNotification().getBody())
                        .setColor(Color.alpha(0x008000))
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
            }
```

this happens 1 time out of maybe 10 times getting a notification

Comment: What is the size of the icon?

Comment: @AmjadAlwareh I have several images size. png image from 256x256, hdpi 36x36, mdpi 24x24, xhdpi 48x48, xxhdpi 72x72, and xxxhdpi 96x96.
is there any requirements for small icon image size ?